# bootstrap: jumbotron with full width and height background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the default jumbotron (within a container)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Example Page</h1>
    <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```

How can I have a background image, inside this jumbotron?

When I add

```
background: url('a.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```

to the `.jumbotron` css class, then I don't get the image across the width. I want it to expand however to atleast fill the jumbotron fully.

Here's the full style

```
    .jumbotron {
      color: white;
      text-shadow: #444 0 1px 1px;
      background:transparent;
      background: url('a.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    }
```

Comment: background-size:cover http://nicolasgallagher.com/flexible-css-cover-images/

Answer (score 0):

You should try placing the jumbotron outside a container

```
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jumbotron can be inside a container and still be full width. Add this rule beneath the background image rule in your CSS:

```
background-size: cover;
```

If it still isn't full width you can add just beneath above rule:

```
width:100%;
```

The jumbotron will likely have rounded corners. If it does and you wish to remove them add this rule:

```
border-radius:0;
```

Try this:

```
.jumbotron {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: #444 0 1px 1px;
  background:transparent;
  background: url('a.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%; // may not need
  border-radius: 0; // override rounded corners if applicable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
background: url('a.jpg') 50% /cover;
```

It's shorthand for

```
background-image: url('a.jpg');
background-position-x: 50%;
background-position-y: center;
background-size: cover;
```

In the `background` shorthand, the value for `background-size` must be placed immediately after the value for `background-position` and prefixed with a `/`.

Note you don't need `center center` in the shorthand. You can use `center` (parsed as `center center` or `50%` (parsed as `50% center`, which is the same as `center center`, but shorter).

Note that without a `background-position` value, `background-size` won't work in the shorthand.

Also note you don't need a `no-repeat` ( = `background-repeat:no-repeat`) here, as elements with `background-size:cover` cannot repeat the background, since it's sized to fit both width and height of element, one of them being cropped (unless your element has exactly the same ratio as the image - in which case none is cropped).

Answer (score -4):

Add an `id` tag to the div class meaning

`div class="jumbotron" id="test"` and in your css file add this

```
#test
{
 background: url('a.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

check if it works

Comment: the specificity of the css selector doesn't have anything to do with maximizing the width to expand full width of container, unless there is a rule you are trying to override from bootstrap by specifying a selector that would have more priority